# Custom RadioButtonComponent - Checkmark disappears with multiple components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've built a custom radio-button component. The problem is, when I use the component multiple times in a page, the checkmark on the other radio button component(s) always disappears, if I select one value of one component. But I have the correct output when I want to access the respective v-model.

If I select an option, the `checkmark:after` disappears from all the other components.

**Page**

```html
<RadioButtonGroup
  v-model="transactionType"
  :options="transactionTypeOptions"
/>
<RadioButtonGroup
  v-model="showAddress"
  :options="showAddressOptions"
/>
<!-- When I select one option in the second component, the checkmark of the first component disappears -->
```

**RadioButtonGroup Component**

```html
<div class="radio-button-group">
  <RadioButton v-for="option in options" :key="option" :option="option" />
</div>
```

```js
props: {
  options: {
    required: true,
    type: Array
  }
}
```

**RadioButton Component**

```html
<label :for="option" class="radio-container">
  {{ option }}
  <input
    :id="option"
    class="radio-input"
    name="radio-input"
    :value="option"
    type="radio"
    @change="$parent.$emit('input', option)"
  />
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

```js
props: {
  option: {
   required: true,
   type: String
  }
}
```

**RadioButton CSS**

```css
.radio-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
  /* Hide the browser's default radio button */
  .radio-input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  /* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
  .radio-input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    border: 1px solid #2196f3;
  }

  /* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
  .radio-input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
  }

  /* Create a custom radio button */
  .checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5px;
    left: 0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  /* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
  .checkmark:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }

  /* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
  .checkmark:after {
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
  }
```

Comment: What do you see in your console/Vue devtools? Any error?

Comment: Nothing...  no error

Comment: Can we also see whats inside the `options` arrays and the `input` function (this: `@change="$parent.$emit('input', option)"`)

Comment: The options, transactionTypeOptions and showAddressOptions, are structured as follows: `['text', 'text']`. @change="$parent... is the function. So I don't have any function under "methods: {}". Or am I missing something?

Comment: Check the emitted event to see if it matched what you look for.